# How to subscribe in redis using codeigniter-predis library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redis

I have to publish "testing" channel and listen into "mytesting()" but publish is successfully done. but on subscribe mytesting() not executed.

```
public function test()
{
    $this->redis_connection();

    $this->redis->publish('testing',"hi");

    try
    {
      $success=$this->redis->subscribe('testing','mytesting');
      print_r($success);

    }catch(Exception $e)
    {
      print_r($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function mytesting($reds, $chan, $stdout)
{
    return $chan;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with subscribe ? which library r u using ? CI has a built-in caching driver for redis - take a look here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html?highlight=redis#redis-caching

Comment: i am using codeigniter-predis library

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this library for subscribe in redis

CodeIgniter Redis : https://github.com/joelcox/codeigniter-redis

Comment: I have already integrated "codeigniter-predis" library in my project